# How to change style and language of timezone

Tags: time, date, style

Ubuntu 23.10

How one to change the STYLE of timezone?
I live in Ukraine, however I do prefer an English version of the system.
But, my date is in Ukrainian language, what is somewhat out of place.

e.g.

Today is ***21st of December, 21.12.2023***

It is shown:
Like ***"гру 21 04:00"*** and I want it to be ***"Dec 21 04:00"***.

(this would be a pleasure if it can be shown just as ***21.12.2023***)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the Language and formats in the Ubuntu Settings.

Go to -> **Settings** -> **Region & Language** -> **Language and Formats**.

You can see the options like in the below screenshot. Change the values to United States and you will get the date format and style that you desire.

[image: Region&Language]